# Working with string data and classification in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, weka

I have a data-set that consists of a pair of a string and the class it belongs to.
The string is a sentence. The class can either be 'male' or 'female'. An example -

'Hi! My name is Jack', male

I am using this as a training set so that, given a different set of strings it can classify whether that statement came from a male or female.
I am using WEKA's **stringtowordvector** to convert the string to a vector containing the count of words in that string.
Using the resultant arff i want it to generate a prediction algorithm (decision trees?) that i can use on an unclassified data-set.
How do i go about it? Which classifier should i use? And which other preprocessing techniques would help in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps a good place to start would be the Simple Message Classifier example ([code](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/example_code/2ed/MessageClassifier.java) and [wiki](http://weka.wikispaces.com/MessageClassifier)) example on the Weka homepage, or maybe 
the [Text Categorization Wiki](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+WEKA).

Pretty much any linear classifier would be a good starting place. I'd suggest either [Logistic Regression](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/Logistic.html) or [Support Vector Machines](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/functions/SMO.html) as a good starting point.

Comment: Your logistic regression and support vector machine links are broken.